# How many replica can one master have in redis?

Tags: redis, replication

In redis, one master can have at most how many replicas?
or is it a memory limit??

I did not find related information.
If you have any related links, I would appreciate it if you posted them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis do not limit the replicas count. Usually, many replicas are not recommended, because it is not friendly for CPU and network bandwidth.

If you want much more replicas, recommended solution is configuring slave of slave, to compose the master -> slave -> slave link.